# Threads issue between Tomcat and RxJava when using Schedulers

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, spring-boot, rx-java, tomcat8

I have a web application that simply acts as a Front Controller using Spring Boot to call other remote REST services where I am combining Spring's DeferredResult with Observables subscribed on Scheduler.computation().

We are also using JMeter to stress out the web application, and we have noticed that requests start to fail with a 500 status, no response data and no logs anywhere when the number of concurrent threads scheduled in JMeter increases from 25, which obviously is a very "manageable" number for Tomcat.

Digging into the issue with the use of VisualVM to analyze how the threads were being created and used, we realized that the use of rx.Schedulers was somehow impacting the number of threads created by Tomcat NIO. Let me summarize our tests based on the rx.Scheduler used and a test in JMeter with 100 users (threads):

1. SCHEDULERS.COMPUTATION()

As we're using the Schedulers.computation() and my local machine has 4 available processors, then 4 EventLoop thread pools are created by RxJava (named RxComputationThreadPool-XXX) and ONLY 10 of Tomcat (named http-nio-8080-exec-XXX), as per VisualVM:

http://screencast.com/t/7C9La6K4Kt6

2. SCHEDULERS.IO() / SCHEDULERS.NEWTHREAD()

This scheduler seems to basically act as the Scheduler.newThread(), so a new thread is always created when required. Again, we can see lots of threads created by RxJava (named RxNewThreadScheduler-XXX), but ONLY 10 for Tomcat (named http-nio-8080-exec-XXX), as per VisualVM:

http://screencast.com/t/K7VWhkxci09o

4. SCHEDULERS.IMMEDIATE() / NO SCHEDULER

If we disable the creation of new threads in RxJava, either by setting the Schedulers.immediate() or removing it from the Observable, then we see the expected behaviour from Tomcat's threads, i.e. 100 http-nio-8080-exec corresponding to the number of users defined for the JMeter test:

http://screencast.com/t/n9TLVZGJ

Therefore, based on our testing, it's clear to us that the combination of RxJava with Schedulers and Tomcat 8 is somehow constraining the number of threads created by Tomcat... And we have no idea why or how this is happening.

Any help would be much appreciated as this is blocking our development so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you debug your application and put a breakpoint on any exception? For the immediate() case, your code probably slows/hangs Tomcat's worker threads and this is why you see so many of them.

Comment: @akarnokd, actually in the immediate() case I do see the expected number of threads from Tomcat, i.e. 100.

Comment: This is odd. Maybe Tomcat checks how many other threads are running and limits itself to 10 threads total. I never heard of such behavior in respect to Tomcat though.